# extract pattern using powershell script

Tags: regex, extract

My bad, I have updated the question-its using Powershell
my file contains 1000s of lines like below:

```
<dependency org="${abcd}" name="some-random-name" rev="100.100" conf="compile;runtime"/>
```

I would like to get only the output like:
name="some-random-name"

how can i achieve this. please help

Answer (score 0):

This probably will solve your issue:

```
cat <file> | grep -oP 'name="[\w-]*"'
```

---

Explaining:

- `grep` is the tool that print lines matching a pattern
- `-o` option will print only the matching parts
- `-P` option will use Perl-style regex in order to allow the `\w` metacharacter.
- `[\w-]*` will match any string containing only 'word' characters or dash with size >= 0

Comment: I copied the file to linux machine and tried using this command, but it is not showing all the tags. I have close to 50, but this command is showing up around 20. But thanks for help though. Is there any way we get all the tags listed

Comment: Give me one example of line not being showed, please